# Where are Azure Function dependencies ( DLLs ) located in the cloud?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Currently, I have a traditional microservices architecture that is deployed to servers in a data-center.

I have a C# DLL that is compiled into my apps (C# Windows Services and web services).

This DLL exposes a C# API that translates calls into http requests sent to a vendor SOAP API.  The DLL has many dependencies on various vendor libraries.

On deploy to server (such as web-server with IIS), the dependency DLLs are typically all located in the web-app \bin folder.

For an Azure Function (coded in a CLR such as C#) the project can include dependencies on NuGet Packages (DLLs).

Once the Azure Function is deployed to Azure cloud, where are the DLLs located in the cloud ?   In blob storage ?  Or where ?

Comment: Are you deploying your `Azure Function` to `Windows` or `Linux` App Service ?And what is the `Plan Type` you are using?

Comment: Once you deploy the Function App, all the dll's /dependencies will be deployed to the `wwwroot/bin` folder.[Image from KUDU Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTFVa.png).

Comment: Link to Open the KUDU Console `https://FunctionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/`.

Answer (score 1):

> Where are Azure Function dependencies ( DLLs ) located in the cloud?

Check the below workaround to see the deployed Function App dependencies and dll`s for a Function App deployed in Azure App Service Windows.

- I have created a new sample `Azure Function`.
- As a workaround added a sample class library within the same project.
- Added the class library reference in the Azure Function.

[image]

- Now deploy the Function App to `Azure App Service`.
- Navigate to the Azure Functions in Portal.

All the `dll's /dependencies` will be deployed to the `wwwroot/bin` folder.

- We can see the deployed `files/folders/dll's` in 2 ways.

***Way1 :***

- `App Service Editor (Preview)` => `Open Editor`

[image]

`WWWROOT` => `bin`

[image]

- We can see the referenced class library and the other dll files are visible under `wwwroot\bin` folder.

***Way 2 :***
`Advanced Tools` => `Go`

[image]

`Debug console` => `CMD` => `site` => `wwwroot` => `bin`

[image]

> where are the DLLs located in the cloud ? In blob storage ? Or where ?

AFAIK,  storing the dll's in Storage Account is not the better approach, as it  includes additional steps to download and use the files.

Where as if we store the dlls in the place where we deploy the app, we can directly reference and use the files without any additional coding.